# How to monitor node http requests in node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

How can I monitor http requests that were made by node in node-webkit? When I make a request I don't see it in the developer tools. I can see the request only when I make it with jquery or xmlhttprequest.

I've binded a console.log on the 'end' event and I can see that node-webkit is actually doing the request and it's returning me a correct response. But doing this blind requests is very hard because there is absolutely no way to debug them (except for logging the params that I've called the request method with).

Answer (score 0):

Such low-level procedures can only be handled by the supported node.js so one of these node.js functions is bound to solve your HTTP header monitoring problem:

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_checkexpectation